# Compression without Mod_Deflate

Tags: .htaccess, compression, performance, mod-deflate

Greetings all,

After running tests with Google PageSpeed, I believe my site could really benefit from compressing js/html/css/php files.  Unfortunately, my host (Host Gator) does not support Mod_Gzip or Mod_Deflate.  I was able to enable php compression through the ini file.

Is there another way to serve compressed files to browsers that support them, in a manner similar to Mod_Deflate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered here:
http://www.joycebabu.com/blog/enabling-gzip-compression-if-mod_gzip-is-not-enabled.html